# Список, цикл for, условный оператор

Tags: python, if, for

Возможно, это самый глупый вопрос, но почему элементам списка не присваивается значение по модулю?

Код:

```
a=[]

for i in range(20):
    a.append(random.randint(-100,100))
print(a)

for j in a:
    if j<0:
        j=abs(j)
print(a)
```

Вывод:

```
[72, -100, 38, 75, 44, -36, -39, -80, 55, -21, 55, -44, 28, 61, 97, -81, 84, 29, -76, -12]

[72, -100, 38, 75, 44, -36, -39, -80, 55, -21, 55, -44, 28, 61, 97, -81, 84, 29, -76, -12]
```

Что не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В цикле

```
for j in a:
```

переменная `j` пробегает по элементам списка `a`. То есть каждую итерацию цикла в неё записывается следующее значение из списка. Соответственно, `j` ничего не знает о списке. И запись в неё нового значения никак не влияет на список. Чтобы менять значения списка в цикле, нужно бежать по индексам списка:

```
for j in range(len(a)):
    if a[j] < 0:
        a[j] = abs(a[j])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import random
a=[]
for i in range(20):
    a.append(random.randint(-100,100))

print(a)
[69, 19, 98, 46, -20, -23, -5, -98, 45, -89, 72, -19, -91, 5, -1, 25, -38, 78, -97, 93]

for i, j in enumerate(a):
    if j<0:
        a[i]=abs(j)   # <-------- a[i]


print(a)
[69, 19, 98, 46, 20, 23, 5, 98, 45, 89, 72, 19, 91, 5, 1, 25, 38, 78, 97, 93]
```

Comment: А почему у меня-то ничего не срабатывает?

Comment: @VyQwe потому, что `j` - это значение элемента, а не сам элемент.

Answer (score 1):

Как вам уже объяснили, изменяя `j` вы не изменяете элемент списка, только эту переменную. Просто добавлю еще один вариант с использованием list comprehensions.

```
import random

a = [random.randint(-100,100) for i in range(20)]
print(a)

a = [abs(j) for j in a]
print(a)
```

Результат:

```
[-17, -89, -46, -93, 53, -19, 92, -91, 56, -73, 45, 37, 82, 27, -60, 15, 2, 47, -24, 33]
[17, 89, 46, 93, 53, 19, 92, 91, 56, 73, 45, 37, 82, 27, 60, 15, 2, 47, 24, 33]
```

Comment: Спасибо.  
Я нашел способ еще короче:

`print([abs(i) for i in a])`

Только я не до конца понимаю, почему этот цикл должен быть в квадратных скобках.)

Comment: Да, точно, условие тут не нужно. Исправил.

Comment: Квадратные скобки говорят о том, что результатом будет список. Такой синтаксис. Таким же способом - в одну строку - можно создавать и словари, например. А если использовать круглые скобки, то в итоге получим генератор.